# delete cached credentials for SMB mount in OSX?

Tags: macos, bash, mount

I am trying to figure out how to delete my saved credentials when I mount a share to my Windows server. I've tried deleting any mentions of the particular server from within Keychain, but I still log in automatically when doing a new mount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within Keychain Access go to the menu and select "Ticket Viewer". I was able to delete my kerberos ticket there. I also read that klist and destroy would work from the command line, but klist does not show any tickets on Mavericks